# Defining an API for complex View generator function (with many configurables)

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a view generator for my Django project. I have a large number of models from a legacy application (~150 models), that all need the same basic CRUD operations (providing Admin access isn't enough apparently).

So I'm writing a generator that returns 5 Views for each model, and of course each view can potentially take a large number of options, and I'm trying to define sane API/default parameter format for my generator.

My current generator:

```
def generate_views(model_class, **kwargs):
    """
    For a given model, returns a dict of generic class-based views
    """
    ###
    # Forms
    #   Optionally generate form classes if not already provided
    ###

    # Append these fields with either "create_" or "update_" to have them only
    # apply to that specific type of form
    form_override_args = ['fields', 'exclude', 'form_method', 'form_class',
                          'form_layout', 'widgets', 'media_css', 'media_js']

    if 'form_class' not in kwargs and 'create_form_class' not in kwargs:
        create_form_kwargs = kwargs.copy()
        for arg in form_override_args:
            if f'create_{arg}' in kwargs:
                create_form_kwargs[arg] = kwargs[f'create_{arg}']
        kwargs['create_form_class'] = forms.FormFactory(model_class, **create_form_kwargs).form()

    if 'form_class' not in kwargs and 'update_form_class' not in kwargs:
        update_form_kwargs = kwargs.copy()
        for arg in form_override_args:
            if f'update_{arg}' in kwargs:
                update_form_kwargs[arg] = kwargs[f'update_{arg}']
        kwargs['update_form_class'] = forms.FormFactory(model_class, **update_form_kwargs).form()

    if 'form_class' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['form_class'] = forms.FormFactory(model_class, **kwargs).form()

    ###
    # Tables
    #   Optionally generate table classes if not already provided
    ###

    # Append these fields with "table_" to have them only
    # apply to the table view
    table_override_args = ['fields', 'exclude']

    if 'table_class' not in kwargs:
        update_table_kwargs = kwargs.copy()
        for arg in table_override_args:
            if f'table_{arg}' in kwargs:
                update_table_kwargs[arg] = kwargs[f'table_{arg}']
        kwargs['table_class'] = tables.TableFactory(model_class, **update_table_kwargs).table()

    ###
    # Views
    #   Generate 5 generic views based on the provided model
    ###
    view_factory = views.ViewFactory(model_class, **kwargs)

    return {
        'list_view': view_factory.list_view(),
        'detail_view': view_factory.detail_view(),
        'create_view': view_factory.create_view(),
        'update_view': view_factory.update_view(),
        'delete_view': view_factory.delete_view()
    }
```

I'm currently relying on `kwargs`, and I wanted to define what a fully filled-out `kwargs` dict should look like. Something like

```
{
    'forms': {
        'all': {

        },
        'create': {

        },
        'update': {

        }
    },
    'tables': {
        'all': {

        },
        'list': {

        }
    },
    'views': {
        'all': {

        },
        'list': {

        },
        'detail': {

        },
        'create': {

        },
        'update': {

        },
        'delete': {

        }
    }
}
```

And it's just seeming a bit overworked. I'm mostly looking for recommendations on a potentially better design (because I'm going cross eyed from just working on it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are fighting the way how Django structures discrete functionalities/configurations in [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#building-up-django-s-generic-class-based-views).

> Django’s generic class-based views are built out of mixins providing discrete functionality.

So, my suggestion is: *using mixins to incoporate the `table` and `form` classes into your views for the CRUD operation*. In the generator, all configurable parameters should be passed **only to the views**.

### Backgrounds knowledge

Let's look at how [`django.views.generic.edit.CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) is designed. It inherits methods and attributes from:
 `SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin`,
 `BaseCreateView` and
 `ModelFormMixin`.
It can be bound to a model simply with a few lines of codes:

```
from myapp.models import Author
class AuthorCreateView(CreateView):
    model  = Author
    fields = ['FirstName','FamilyName','BirthDay']
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Saves the form instance, sets the current object for the view, and redirects to get_success_url().
```

Here the `model` attribute is shared by all the mixins to do their jobs, while `fields` and `form_valid` are specific to `ModelFormMixin`. 
Although all configurable parameters/methods are put together under the View class, each mixin just picks up those it needs.

### Redesign the API

Keeping this in mind, let's begin to simplify your view generator/factory. For this example, let's say you have the following base classes that include common (default) settings:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, DeleteView, UpdateView
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django_tables2 as SingleTableMixin

class TableListView(SingleTableMixin, ListView):
    table_pagination = { 'per_page': 10 }
    # add common configurable parameters here

class MyOwnCreateView(CreateView):
    success_url = "/yeah"
    # Introduce a configurable method `form_valid_hook`
    def form_valid(self, form):
        if hasattr(self,'form_valid_hook'):
            self.form_valid_hook(form)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Below is the simplified generator function for all 5 views.

```
BaseViews= {'create': MyOwnCreateView,
            'delete': DeleteView,
            'update': UpdateView,
            'list'  : TableListView,
            'detail': DetailView }

def generate_views(model_class, **kwargs):
    """
    Generate views for `model_class`

    Keyword parameters:
        {action}=dict(...)
        {action}_mixins=tuple(...)
        where `action` can be 'list', 'detail', 'create', 'update', 'delete'.
    """
    NewViews = {}
    for action, baseView in BaseViews.items():
        viewName = model_class.__name__ + baseView.__name__
        viewAttributes = kwargs.get(action,{})
        viewBaseCls = (baseView,) + kwargs.get(f"{action}_mixins",tuple())
        v = type(viewName, viewBaseCls, viewAttributes) # create a subclass of baseView
        v.model = model_class # bind the view to the model
        NewViews[f'{action}_view'] = v
    return NewViews
```

You see, the generator function is simplified to **only 10 lines** of code.
Moreover, the API will become much cleaner:

```
def validate_author(self, form):
    send_email(form)

AuthorViews = generate_views(Author, 
                             create=dict(
                                 success_url='/thanks/',
                                 form_valid_hook=validate_author), 
                             ... )
```

### How to use mixins in this API

In the above example, I use a hook/callback function `form_valid_hook` to inject an email-sending procedure before the form data are saved. This is ugly because the configurables for the email will be in the module scope. It's better to refactor it into a mixin class.

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class FormEmailMixin:
    from_email = 'info@example.com'
    subject_template = 'We hear you'
    message_template = 'Hi {username}, ...'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user_info = dict( username = self.request.user.username
                          to_email = ... )
        send_mail(subject_template.format(**user_info),
                  message_template.format(**user_info)
                  self.from_email , [user_info['to_email'],] )
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Then you can use this mixin class in the API call.

```
AuthorViews = generate_views( Author, 
                  create={ 'message_template': 'Dear Author {username}, ...' }, 
                  create_mixins = (FormEmailMixin,) )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding to this. Unfortunately, this is a personal project, so I had to step away for a few days. Nonetheless...I think this looks great, definitely had to read it a few times to really comprehend the design, but I think it makes a lot of sense. The only thing that doesn't seem clear to me in your examples, is how, for example, I could use the `{action}_mixins`. Would you mind possibly including an example of that as well?

Comment: This is great! Thanks again for the help!